# regex perl capture between two same tags across multiple lines in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I 've a lot of tab delimited text files where I need to capture everything between the same words across the test, the input looks like this

```
H string
H string
H string
SCAN 00001 00001
I string
I string
432.203 194090 0
SCAN 00002 00002
```

with the same pattern (several lines starting with I and then the numbers I need to capture) the scans are ordered from lowest to highest and they are unique. between two "SCAN" there are only numbers divided in 3 column space delimited and I need to extract the first and second number, between two scans there are circa two-three thousands rows composed by 3 numbers.

I'm not the god of regular expression but I was trying with this

```
while (<$fh_2>)
{
chomp;
next if (/^H/);

my $sc;

if (/(^S.+[\d]+)/../^S.+[\d]+/ms) #while we are between two ^S
{
my @sc_line= split /\s/, $1; #capture the scan number
$sc= pop @sc_line;
if (/(^[\d]+\.?[\d]*)/) # if there are numbers (m) at the start 
   {
    my @lines = split /\s/, $_;
    push @ms, $1; #capture the first number
    push @int, $lines[1]; #capture the second number (i)
    $m{$sc} = [@ms]; #create hash of array
    $in{$sc}= [@int];
   }
}
```

The main problem is that I want to have everything after a particular scan be matched to that scan somehow but due to the fact that the pattern is the same I found tricky to write it.

The output has to be an hash of arrays or multi dimensional hash where for every scan I can associate every first number (m) and (i) number, it can be two separate hashes or not it does not matter as long as I can retrieve the arrays from the scan number.
EDIT: I solved it in another way

```
while (<$fh_2>)
{
chomp;

next if (/^H/);

if (/^S/) 
{ 
my @sc_line= split /\s/, $_;
my $sc_= pop @sc_line;
push @sc, $sc_;
push @count, scalar @int;
}
    elsif (/(^[\d]+\.?[\d]*)/)
    {
    my @lines = split /\s/, $_;
    push @ms, $1;
    push @int, $lines[1];
    }

}
close $fh_2;
```

I'm using indexes for getting the number of element of @int (or @ms) everytime @sc gets a new element, it was silly to not think about it at first.
Still interested to see if there is any TIMTOWTDI magic going on.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can your try to clarify it? For example, what do specifically are you trying to extract from the example data that you gave? Are you only interested in the `SCAN` lines? If so, are you only interested in `SCAN` lines for which the numbers differ?

Comment: Even a demigod is able to provide ***real world input strings***.

Comment: Better provide the sample output

Comment: @GillesQuenot added

Comment: @redneb I edited the question tell me if it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I hope this provides a solution, at least half way towards your needs. Suggest modifications (or modify yourself) to make it a complete match as per your requirements.

Here is sample data:

```
H string
H string
H string
SCAN 00001 00001
I string
I string
432.203 194090 0
221.332 983451 0
SCAN 00002 00002
H string
H string
H string
SCAN 00001 00003
I string
I string
521.193 182233 0
522.103 171211 0
SCAN 00004 00004
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


# Store information about scans in the form of hash of hashes
my %scans=();

# The current scan number
my $scannumber="";

while (my $line=<>) {

   chomp($line);
   #print "Current Line: $line\n";

   if ($line=~m/^SCAN (\d+) (\g1)/) {
      $scannumber="$1";
      #print "New Scan: $scannumber\n";
   }
   elsif ($line=~m/^(\d+.\d+) (\d+)/) {
      my ($key,$val)=("$1","$2");
      #print "$key : $val\n";
      $scans{$scannumber}{$key}=$val;
   }

}


## You are ready to print the hash of hashes now
#
for my $scannumber (sort keys %scans) {

   for my $key (sort keys %{$scans{$scannumber}}) {

      my $val=$scans{$scannumber}{$key};
      print "$scannumber : $key : $val\n";
   }
}


## You could also print the hash of hashes like this
#
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 2;

print "\n\n";
print Dumper(\%scans);
```

Sample run of the script:

```
~> cat data1 | ./script.pl
00001 : 221.332 : 983451
00001 : 432.203 : 194090
00002 : 521.193 : 182233
00002 : 522.103 : 171211


{
  '00002' => {
               '522.103' => '171211',
               '521.193' => '182233'
             },
  '00001' => {
               '221.332' => '983451',
               '432.203' => '194090'
             }
}
```

Comment: The output needs to be two arrays cause I need to conserve the order of two values so two hashes with scan as keys and arrays as value or multi dimensional where I attach two array to the same hash. also the files are pretty long (51000 scans more or less) with couple of thousands of rows between them (different length) so I need to be able dinamically to catch everything that's numeric but conserving the order between them

Comment: @D.A., I added another answer that preserves the order of scanlines within each scan number. I left the first answer as-is in order for  you to be able to select whichever suits your needs most.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script to do it as two hashes of arrays. They preserve the order of scan lines within each scan number. Give it a try and see if it serves your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %m=();
my %in=();
my $sn="";

while (my $line=<>) {
   chomp($line);

   if ($line=~m/^SCAN (\d+) (\g1)/) {
     $sn="$1";
   }
   elsif ($line=~m/^(\d+.\d+) (\d+)/) {
     push(@{$m{$sn}},$1); push(@{$in{$sn}},$2);
   }
}


## You could also print the hash of hashes like this
#
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 2;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

print "Here is the dump of results:\n";
print "m = ".(Dumper(\%m))."\nin = ".(Dumper(\%in));


## Printing manually
#
print "\nHere is how you can print them manually:\n";
for my $sn (sort keys %m) {
   for my $i (0..scalar(@{$m{$sn}})-1) {
      print "ScanNumber<$sn> First<$m{$sn}[$i]> Second<$in{$sn}[$i]>\n";
   }
}
```

Here is the sample data:

```
H string
H string
H string
SCAN 00001 00001
I string
I string
100.100 100000 0
200.200 200000 0
SCAN 00002 00002
H string
H string
H string
300.300 300000 0
400.400 400000 0
500.500 500000 0
600.600 600000 0
700.700 700000 0
800.800 800000 0
900.900 900000 0
SCAN 00001 00003
```

Here is output of command run as: *./script.pl < data*

```
Here is the dump of results:
m = {
  '00001' => [
               '100.100',
               '200.200'
             ],
  '00002' => [
               '300.300',
               '400.400',
               '500.500',
               '600.600',
               '700.700',
               '800.800',
               '900.900'
             ]
}

in = {
  '00001' => [
               '100000',
               '200000'
             ],
  '00002' => [
               '300000',
               '400000',
               '500000',
               '600000',
               '700000',
               '800000',
               '900000'
             ]
}

Here is how you can print them manually:
ScanNumber<00001> First<100.100> Second<100000>
ScanNumber<00001> First<200.200> Second<200000>
ScanNumber<00002> First<300.300> Second<300000>
ScanNumber<00002> First<400.400> Second<400000>
ScanNumber<00002> First<500.500> Second<500000>
ScanNumber<00002> First<600.600> Second<600000>
ScanNumber<00002> First<700.700> Second<700000>
ScanNumber<00002> First<800.800> Second<800000>
ScanNumber<00002> First<900.900> Second<900000>
```